# Read specific column and row value from a text file using Python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-2.7

I have a text file as following:

```
1.25        177.        
1.50        220.        
2.00        272.        
5.00        427.    
10.00       556.        
25.00       763.        
50.00       916.
```

and i want to read second last value from second column. I can move onto line of interest but somehow can't figure out a way to read required value. Any help would be appreciative.

```
a = open("test.txt","r")
b = a.readlines()
a.close()

count = 0
for line in b:
    count += 1
    if count > 6:
        print line,
```

Comment: Does this question belong on GIS.SE?  How is this GIS related?

Comment: What are the corner cases for your example? Will there always be a trailing .? Will the second column always be 3 digits long?

Comment: This really should be a [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) question.

Comment: @Fetzer et al. I agree on it. Text file results are used as string in conjunction with shapefile attributes which led me to post it here. But the question only as it is posted here should be on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. The quickest would be to read the file as you have done and then use the string `split` function.

```py
b = open("test.txt", "r").readlines()
line = b[-2].split() #Gets the second last value from the list and split on whitespace
return float(line[-1])
```

However this isn't very reusable. If you're doing this for lots of similar files I'd look at the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html) for working with delimited text.

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open("input.txt", 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()



for line in lines:
    parts = line.split() # split line into parts
    if len(parts) > 1:
        column2 = parts[1]
        columnLength = len(column2)
        desireValue = column2[columnLength-3]
        print desireValue
```

for given text file in the question, this code will print 
7
2
7
2
5
6
1

Comment: What is the reason behind the down vote ??!!